# How to make a recursive function call with a long press of a button

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have a button that controls the sound, I want to make it so that with a long press of the button, the sound will gradually increase. How to do it? (I have the logic to increase and decrease the sound)

Comment: What's the hard part? Why do you require "recursive"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope this helps you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var volumeUpButton: UIButton!

var shouldIncreaseVolume: Bool = false { didSet { if shouldIncreaseVolume { volumeLoop() } } }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(increaseVolumeHandler))
    volumeUpButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

@objc
func increaseVolumeHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        shouldIncreaseVolume = true
        break

    default:
        shouldIncreaseVolume = false
        break
    }
}

func volumeLoop() {
    // You can alter the time from 0.1 to any value as per your requirement.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        if self.shouldIncreaseVolume {
            self.volumeLoop()
            print("(+) Call increase volume method here.")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks